# Read data in the View XML file? [Titanium]

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-alloy

I am curious that if we can read the data that is passed by the previous controller in the (next)View (XML) file in Titanium? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a possible way to acces the $.args.variable in the xml nor the tss file unless the variable value is a bool, the only thing possible to do with it is adding conditional styles or conditional view tags:

a full example on conditional tss and xml tags can be found [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Alloy_Styles_and_Themes)